# How to pivot a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that contains two rows and I wanted to use the first row as a header in a new df.

This is what my data looks like:

| ver | time |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2.31 |
| b | 3.45 |
| b | 3.75 |
| a | 2.21 |
| b | 3.87 |
| b | 4.02 |
| a | 1.97 |
| a | 3.56 |

This is what I am trying to get:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 2.31 | 3.45 |
| 2.21 | 3.75 |
| 1.97 | 3.87 |
| 3.56 | 4.02 |

Comment: These sorts of questions are not ones that should be submitted to stackoverflow.  You will find your answer here.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: Q/A #10 in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `cumcount` create the key then `pivot`

```
out = df.assign(key=df.groupby('ver').cumcount()).pivot('key','ver','time')
ver     a     b
key            
0    2.31  3.45
1    2.21  3.75
2    1.97  3.87
3    3.56  4.02
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful in getting to what I needed and came in handy on another project.

Comment: @sd_5_1_1 If this help , would you like accept the answer ? check mark at the left